# Does lua command line support threads?

Tags: multithreading, lua

Is there a way to create threads in the default lua command line utility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, "stock" build of Lua doesn't have support for threads at all. You can use your operating system forks to spawn more scripts, or stick to coroutines.

Comment: humm... I really need threads. Do you know if there is a lua library that adds thread support to the command line? something like:
require("threads")  
threads.start(function () while true do print("hello") end end)

Comment: Also, no part of "stock" Lua is thread-safe, so trying to make it multithreaded could cause serious problems.

Comment: @DanielSperry What dualed said above. The best way to use threads with Lua is to spawn a VM for each thread and then communicate. If you really want to do it, it is possible, but not as easy and funky as you'd like. You will need your own Lua build. Lua users wiki is the best available source if you are looking for libraries

Comment: @dualed Lua being thread safe is a bit more nuanced, as indicated by [this post on the mailing list](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-07/msg00072.html). What I make up of this is that separate Lua states are thread safe (as in OS thread), but Lua threads (as in coroutines) are not.

Answer (score 3):

As Bartek said there is no support for threads in stock Lua, but you can add thread support to the CLI thanks to the Lua Lanes library (see http://www.luteus.biz/Download/LoriotPro_Doc/LUA/LUA_For_Windows/lanes/index.html / https://github.com/LuaLanes )

Comment: Excellent! I managed to use lualanes in the command line as I wanted.